# extracting value from a <ul> with specific text text using HTMLAgilitypack

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract a link from http://www.raws.dri.edu/cgi-bin/rawLIST.pl?idIAN1+id
this site contains an unsorted list and I want to get the link for Daily Summary.

So far I've tried using an xpath string of `"//ul/li/a"` using the `.SelectNodes()` method.  Doing so returns only the first item in the list which is what I want but ultimately in the future I may want to get the link to a different page so being able to specify which link to retrieve is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `//ul/li/a`, you should get *all* the `<a>` links, not one.

If you want to extract the links that contain some text (e.g. `Time Series Graph`), you can do:

```
//ul/li/a[contains(text(), 'Time Series Graph')]
```

Similar, if you're looking for some specific text in the `href` attribute:

```
//ul/li/a[contains(@href, 'Time Series Graph')]
```

By the way, I see [you have asked many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3421997/user3421997?tab=questions) pointing to the same website, etc. My suggestion is: Learn a little bit of XPath, the basics, and read a tutorial about how HtmlAgilityPack works (pretty simple once you understand the basics of XPath), and then start working on that scraper.